ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch', but torch is installed
I'm trying to use (and have successfully installed) Layout Parser, which requires detectron2 for certain functionality. While trying to install detectron2, I ran into the following error:
> python -m pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git'

[snip]
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
      [end of output]
[/snip]

Setting the flags as specified in the installation instructions does nothing:
CC=clang CXX=clang++ ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip3 install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@v0.4#egg=detectron2'

[same output]


I have torch (2.4.1) and torchvision (0.19.1) installed, and the versions match.
I'm on macOS Sequoia 15.1.1
I'm using Python 3.10.14 and pip 24.2

Full output of the installation command is at this pastebin.

Either downgrade pip to version 22 or run pip install --no-build-isolation.

That worked. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Modern pip uses build isolation, it uses a transient virtual env to build a wheel. For packages that don't require build dependencies or packages that declare build dependencies in pyproject.toml it's not a problem. But the package detectron2 requires torch and doesn't provide pyproject.toml.
You can downgrade to older pip version 22 that doesn't build in an isolated environment. Or disable build isolation using --no-build-isolation. The full command should be
python -m pip install --no-build-isolation 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git'

